# How to merge play Icon with video thumbnail in gridview?

Tags: android

i am developed a application where ***i need to merge video and image into a single gallery*** so we need to differentiate video and image by using video play icon on video thumbnail. i don;t have any idea **how to merge video icon with video thumbnail** please give me idea.

thank you in advance .

Answer (score 2):

Use a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) and two [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)s of the same size. One for the play icon the other for the thumbnail. They will overlap

Answer (score 0):

You can use extend surface view to play video.
I have done this using Media player and Surface view.

Here is the sample code for extending surface view.

```
package com.vt.soc;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TappableSurfaceView extends SurfaceView {
    private ArrayList<TapListener> listeners=new ArrayList<TapListener>();
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private GestureDetector gesture=null;

    public TappableSurfaceView(Context context,
                                                            AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            gestureListener.onSingleTapUp(event);
        }

        return(true);
    }

    public void addTapListener(TapListener l) {
        listeners.add(l);
    }

    public void removeTapListener(TapListener l) {
        listeners.remove(l);
    }

    private GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener gestureListener=
        new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            for (TapListener l : listeners) {
                l.onTap(e);
            }

            return(true);
        }
    };

    public interface TapListener {
        void onTap(MotionEvent event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use framelayout it will work for you`

```
<!-- This for video thumbnail-->
<Imageview 
    layout_width="wrap_content"
    layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<!-- This for video icon in center-->
<Imageview 
    layout_width="50dp"
    layout_height="50dp"/>
```

`